# JAVASCRIPT: Getting NaN result after calling function in document.write()

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, object-properties

I'm trying to get the bornYear as the result with the below code but getting NaN as a result.

```
function person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.yearOfBirth = bornYear;
}
function bornYear(){
    return 2020 - this.age;
}
document.write(bornYear());
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: What is supposed to be `this`? Missing some context

Comment: By the way, the function `bornYear()` will **only** work today, december the 31st. Ignoring the fact that tomorrow the year will change, Tomorrow, doing 2021 - 36 (my age)  will give 1985. I'm born in April 1984

Comment: @Cid You mean it will only work after this year’s birthday, don’t you? This information should also be provided, to get a correct result.

Comment: First of all, why is Person a function, why not  a class? and what is the context of this as @Cid asked?

Comment: @Nikolaus as it's written, it will only work flawlessly the last day of year

Comment: @Cid yes, you’re right I’ve overlooked the word flawlessly. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create an instance of `person`, and you did not call a property of that instance:

- `bornYear` references `this`, which seems intended to be a `person` instance, so you must bind `this` to it somehow.
- As you defined a property `yearOfBirth`, it would be appropriate to call *that* method.

Also, your `bornYear` function is limited to the year 2020. You should take the *current* year, using the `Date` constructor.

Here is how it could work:

```js
function person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.yearOfBirth = bornYear.bind(this); // bind this
}
function bornYear(){
    // Use the current year to calculate year of birth
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
}
// First create an instance, then call the method
document.write(new person("Helen", 18).yearOfBirth());
```

It is more common to define such a method on the prototype though, and to start the constructor name with a capital (`Person`).

Also, using `document.write` is bad practice in this scenario. Use `console.log`.

The standard way would go like this:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    bornYear() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
    }
}
console.log(new Person("Helen", 18).bornYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function bornYear(){
    return 2020 - parseInt(this.age);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up object oriented programming with a functional style of programming. If you want to use `this` like you're doing, you'd have to do something like:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.yearOfBirth = () => {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
    };
}
let newPerson = new Person('Foo', 25);
document.write(newPerson.yearOfBirth());
```